# How to track time log from when task was created to complete

Tags: postgresql, nestjs

Hello great community,

I need your help. I am new to NestJS so I want to build Todo Api with authentication.

Everything is working fine, but I want to implement how to track time log between when the task was created and completed.

For example, I want to keep tack of the time it takes to complete a task.

I am finding this difficult. Any idea will be of great help for me.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you want to track each method? Do you want to  save this information in a store anywhere or just log it? Do you plan to use a tracing API like prometheus or open telemetry?

Comment: @jay McDoniel, Basically, what I want to achieve is to Keep log of time of status changes. The Todo consists of three status ( logged, in progress and finished). The changes will be save to postgres db. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with many methods.
What i would do is through created_at and completed_at db columns.
In the moment when a task is created the created_at column gets the current creation time, than when the task is marked as complete you update and fill the completed_at column with the current completion time. What you would do next is just take the time difference between the two dates.